# How do I check connectivity with a machine on my local network using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, polling

I am able to poll a website using Node.js but how do I check with some local machine.Just want to check if some "xyz" machine is active on the network.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to be more precise on your needs.

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/net-ping/ (?)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you wanna ask though
there is no difference between local servers and global servers.it's a only matter of whether you access to the server from inside of the LAN or outside of it.

if you install HTTP server on the machine you want to check, you can check its status code like usual website's servers.

and there is also modules for ping such as
https://npmjs.org/package/net-ping/
all you have to do is to replace target IP address to private IP address like 192.168.*.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I guess you used `http` to request an address?

If so, if you request a non active machine, you should get an error. To catch this error, simple react at the **error** event:

```
http.get("http://idontexistonthenetwork", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

P.S: Hope it answer your question. Don't hesitate to precise if you need something more specific like using websocket, IP discovering or else...